# Set a default cache control and expires for entire S3 bucket/CloudFront

Tags: caching, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have an amazon S3 bucket with approximately 300K items in it that are used by a large website. I would like to set the expiration of all the objects that are served out of CloudFront from the S3 bucket so that they can be cached in the browser by the user's machine. Is there an easy way to set the cache control on all the s3 objects currently in the bucket **AND** most importantly set a default for the bucket so that any new  items added also gain the expires and cache-control headers **OR** can this be done using CloudFront?

So far i have read a number of AWS documents but have found nothing:

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Steps for adding cache control for existing objects in your bucket**

1. git clone https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd
2. Run s3cmd --configure 
   (You will be asked for the two keys - copy and paste them from your
   confirmation email or from your Amazon account page. Be careful when
   copying them! They are case sensitive and must be entered accurately
   or you'll keep getting errors about invalid signatures or similar.
   Remember to add s3:ListAllMyBuckets permissions to the keys or you will get an AccessDenied error while testing access.)
3. ./s3cmd --recursive modify --add-header="Cache-Control:public ,max-age= 31536000" s3://your_bucket_name/

**For CloudFront** you can specify  Minimum TTL, Maximum TTL, and Default TTL for a cache behavior.they are basically the time for which an object can be cached on CloudFront and **has nothing to do with adding an expiry header for the object i.e it doesn't mody any header**

So now if you haven't added any header, then cloudfront will caches it for DEFAULT TTL.
FOR MORE INFO READFOLLOWING TABLE
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html#ExpirationDownloadDist

Comment: The CloudFront settings "Minimum TTL", "Maximum TTL" and "Default TTL" specify the behaviour of the CloudFront cache, not what headings are set in the HTTP response, correct?

Comment: This does not seem to address the last part of the question.  How do you set the bucket so that new things added in that folder or even the whole bucket get that tag added to them

Comment: CloudFront TTLs are saying for how long should objects be in edge nodes cache and do nothing with client caching

Comment: @boatcoder I wasn't able to find the solution to that part. Do share with me if you are able to find one.

Comment: I'm glad I found this tool. It's such a great thing.

Comment: With AWS CLI the command looks like this:

`aws s3 cp s3://YOUR_BUCKET/ s3://YOUR_BUCKET/ --metadata-directive REPLACE --recursive --cache-control max-age=31536000`

Comment: If you are using aws sync command-line option, you can specify --cache-control max-age=31536000 at end of the command to have that by default whenever a new object is added to s3.